# Ansible critcal AnsibleUndefinedVariable referencing a variable name I am not using

Tags: ansible

I am modifying a pair of tasks on a fully functional playbook, their purpose is to register if a certain file exists per host for each name (agency in the loop variable) and register this information. Next task will create the file only if it is not present for a certain name (agency) in a certain host.

*Notice that certain paths/references on the code have been changed for privacy purposes.*

```
- name: Register if file.asp exists for each agency
  win_stat:
    path: "C:/path/file_{{ agency.agency_name|upper }}_{{ env_name|upper }}.asp"
  register: reportASP_status
  with_items:
    "{{ agencies }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: agency
    label: "{{ agency.agency_name }}"

- name: Generate file.asp locally
  template:
    newline_sequence: "\r\n"
    src: file.asp.j2
    dest: "path/crystal/file_{{ item.agency.agency_name|upper }}_{{ env_name|upper }}.asp"
  loop: "{{ reportASP_status.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.agency.agency_name }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  when:
    not item.stat.exists
```

Registering the current status works fine, I can output the reportASP_status variable and see that all where registered sucessfully. But when generating the file, the existing ones get skipped correctly but, upon reaching one that should be generated, the task fails with the following message:

```
failed: [windows2019] (item=IDontHaveIt) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "agency": {
            "agency_name": "IDontHaveIt",
            "credentials": {
                "report": {
                    "password": 1234567,
                    "username": "username"
                }
            },
            "database_fqdn": "one.db.com",
            "database_name": "IDontHaveIt"
        },
        "ansible_loop_var": "agency",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "checksum_algorithm": "sha1",
                "follow": false,
                "get_checksum": true,
                "path": "C:/PATH/file_IDONTHAVEIT_LOCALDEV.asp"
            }
        },
        "stat": {
            "exists": false
        }
    },
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'crystal' is undefined"
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
```

Problem here is I don't have any variable "crystal" defined, and never have, neither its being referenced on any of the two task's code. I tried running the playbook with --debug and -vvv but I don't get more info on the error. Id like to know how could I start debuging an undefined variable error for a variable that I'm not conciously trying to use. Something in the code must be trying to use it, due to an error on my part, but I fail to see it.

Comment: did you check if it is used in the template?

Comment: 2cent hint for a wide, quick and dirty overview: from your current directory containing your playbooks/roles/inventories/templates... `grep -R crystal *`. If already under git version control, even better: `git grep crystal`.

Comment: Its actually used on the template. Thanks for both the tips. Now I'll try to address the problem and then will come back with an answer to close this, if possible.

Comment: An other way to close this kind of question which are "Not reproducible or caused by a typo" (one of the close vote reasons you will be able to see once you have enough reputation and that the community will most probably cast now we are sure about the cause of the issue) is to delete the question yourself (unless you are absolutely convinced you can provide a self-answer having a real added value for future users.)